# Angular with query params with percent (%2) not rendering page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am at a loss how to solve this problem with the query params does not render the Angular view. I have encoded the string from the back end.

This does not work:

http://localhost:2333/change-password?token=cfdj8ka%2bqsu

This works:

http://localhost:2333/change-password?token=cfdj8ka
http://localhost:2333/change-password?token=cfdj8kabqsu

I believe %2 is the encoded value for `/`. How can I get my Angular route to decode this correctly? I am using Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are  using  this.router.navigate([url]) instead of that use

> this.router.navigateByUrl(url);

In Constructor

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,) { 
   let token= this._route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('token');
}
```

Comment: No, I am opening the URL directly on the browser.

Comment: what you want  get query param form the url  in ts file?

Comment: the page is not rendering as I mentioned in my question because of the %2f. I can retrieve the token in my component if it does load.

Comment: have you tried this._route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('token'); in  constructor where  _route is private _route: ActivatedRoute,

Comment: I removed the code to grab the query params for now, but it doesn't even render the component. Seems like its not finding the path or something.